# What are the common used notation for identifiers in commands?

Tags: naming

I notice that some characters are not allowed in `\def\...` what are the common rule to separate words in LaTeX command?

1. camelCase?
2. kebab-case?
3. snake_case?
4. other?

For example how should the command `project title` be named?

Comment: (2) and (3) are not allowed with normal document settings (3) is standard L3 code stye

Comment: In LaTeX commands only letters are allowed,neither `-` nor `_`. For internal LaTeX commands also `@` are used, but without extra effort this is allowed in packages and classes only. In the `expl3` context some other characters are also valid. So an answer depends on what you are doing. BTW: In LaTeX preambles you should avoid `\def` and prefer `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand`, `\NewDocumentCommand` etc.

Comment: If you are writing a package for others to use: Be sure that your commands use a "namespace" prefix. Bad: `\dothis`. Good: `\zzdothis` where `zz` is related to your package name. Same for internal package commands. That prevents conflict with other packages trying to use the same macro names.